# How to convert request data to json in AWS Lambda services?

Tags: json, string, aws-lambda, request

```
"error%5Bcode%5D=BAD_REQUEST_ERROR&error%5Bdescription%5D=Payment+failed&error%5Bsource%5D=gateway&error%5Bstep%5D=payment_authorization&error%5Breason%5D=payment_failed&error%5Bmetadata%5D=%7B%22payment_id%22%3A%22pay_Es97gMGzx61l1u%22%2C%22order_id%22%3A%22order_Es96Rxp5OmnVVF%22%7D"
```

We are currently migrating to Lambda services from Flask. In Flask I was able to get the data in dictionary but in the AWS Lambda services, I am receiving the data as string, does anyone know how to parse this or convert it into a json or dictionary?

Thanks for ur time (:

Answer (score 0):

This example string looks like an encode URI String. Where do you get it ? Could you provide more informations about usage context : API Gateway or request from another lambda, and how do you get this this?

With Pyhton usually you can get the path parameters and the query string parameters as a dictionnary with :

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    params = event["pathParameters"]
    query = event["queryStringParameters"]
```